# Compose Preview not working in Android Studio when using permissions (appcompanist)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

When I add this line in my composable, the preview gives exception.

Code:  `val locationPermissionsState = rememberMultiplePermissionsState( listOf( Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION ) )`

Exception message is "This preview was unable to find a CompositionLocal, and the stack trace is

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Permissions should be called in the context of an Activity
> at com.google.accompanist.permissions.PermissionsUtilKt.findActivity(PermissionsUtil.kt:138)
> at com.google.accompanist.permissions.MutableMultiplePermissionsStateKt.rememberMutablePermissionsState(MutableMultiplePermissionsState.kt:80)
> at com.google.accompanist.permissions.MutableMultiplePermissionsStateKt.rememberMutableMultiplePermissionsState(MutableMultiplePermissionsState.kt:48)
> at com.google.accompanist.permissions.MultiplePermissionsStateKt.rememberMultiplePermissionsState(MultiplePermissionsState.kt:38)

Comment: The app is working fine and exactly as it should, but just the preview in Android Studio doesn't work with this thing, which makes the development a little difficult. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I was able to preview composable functions in Android Studio (Electric Eel) that use the `MultiplePermissionsState` interface by implementing the interface and hardcoding the necessary state for the preview.

Here is an example:

```
@ExperimentalPermissionsApi
class MultiplePermissionsStatePreview : MultiplePermissionsState {

    override val allPermissionsGranted: Boolean
        get() = false

    override val permissions: List<PermissionState>
        get() = emptyList()

    override val revokedPermissions: List<PermissionState>
        get() = emptyList()

    override val shouldShowRationale: Boolean
        get() = true

    override fun launchMultiplePermissionRequest() {
        // do nothing
    }
}

@ExperimentalPermissionsApi
@Preview
@Composable
private fun PermissionsPreview() {
    AppTheme {
        PermissionsScreen(
            multiplePermissionsState = MultiplePermissionsStatePreview()
            // ...
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is due to failure of finding the activity context that `remember...PermissionState()` calls under the hood.

Fortunately, both `PermissionState` and `MultiplePermissionState` are interfaces.

You can easily workaround the problem by implementing a no-op permission state for use with a preview.

The simplest possible implementation:

```kotlin
@OptIn(ExperimentalPermissionsApi::class)
internal class PreviewPermissionState(
  override val status: PermissionStatus
) : PermissionState {

  override val permission: String
    get() = ""

  override fun launchPermissionRequest() {
    // No-op by design.
  }
}
```

With a `remember` function:

```kotlin
@Composable
@OptIn(ExperimentalPermissionsApi::class)
fun rememberPreviewPermissionState(granted: Boolean): PermissionState {

  val status = when (granted) {
    true -> PermissionStatus.Granted
    false -> PermissionStatus.Denied(shouldShowRationale = false)
  }

  return remember(granted) { PreviewPermissionState(status = status) }
}
```

**Program to interfaces not implementations.**

Having all that in place, you can use it as follows:

```kotlin
// Local inspection mode returns "true" for preview.
val inspection = LocalInspectionMode.current

// Use no-op state for preview and regular implementation
// for runtime.
val cameraPermission = when (inspection) {
  true -> rememberPreviewPermissionState(granted = false)
  false -> rememberPermissionState(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
}
```

Exactly the same technique can be incorporated for the `MultiplePermissionState` alternative that is used to handle multiple permissions at once.